# keystore password verification failed at nexus starting

Tags: passwords, jetty, ssl-certificate, keystore, nexus

I generated my self-signed certificate as follows:
sudo keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias jetty  -keystore keystore.jks -storepass myjettypassword -validity 360 -keysize 2048

when keystore.jks was generated, I started nexus(with jetty embedded) but got this error. Please help!

2016-03-17 16:09:04,084-0400 WARN  [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED SslContextFactory@4baf273d(./conf/ssl/keystore.jks,./conf/ssl/keystore.jks): java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
jvm 1    |  at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:772) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
jvm 1    |  at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
jvm 1    |  at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1226) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(CertificateUtils.java:55) ~[jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.getKeyStore(SslContextFactory.java:1053) ~[jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadTrustStore(SslContextFactory.java:1027) ~[jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:265) ~[jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector.doStart(SslSelectChannelConnector.java:612) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |  at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.InstrumentedSslSelectChannelConnector.doStart(InstrumentedSslSelectChannelConnector.java:91) [nexus-bootstrap-2.12.0-01.jar:2.12.0-01]
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
jvm 1    |  at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer$JettyMainThread.run(JettyServer.java:247) [nexus-bootstrap-2.12.0-01.jar:2.12.0-01]
jvm 1    | Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed

Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
jvm 1    |  at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:770) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
jvm 1    |  ... 13 common frames omitted
jvm 1    | 2016-03-17 15:02:20,808-0400 ERROR [WrapperListener_start_runner] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - Start failed
jvm 1    | java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Answer (score 1):

From this all I can tell you is that the keystore file is corrupted.

Luckily, you can just delete it:

sonatype-work/nexus/conf/ssl/keystore.jks

It will be rebuilt from certificates stored in the capabilities configuration of Nexus.